# how to use if else in nested switch case

Tags: java

whenever I'm running the loop 
"if loop" was running properly but, else one showing a syntax error message
does switch case support if else looping or not??
and one more doubt is how to prepare for the ocjp certification itself.

```
public static void main(String ah[])
    {
    int a,b,c,d=0,ch;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter two number ");

    a=sc.nextInt();
    b=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter your choise \n1.add\n2.sub\3.div\4.multi ");
    ch=sc.nextInt();
    switch(ch)
    {
    case 1:
        c=a+b;
        System.out.println("sum is = "+c);
        break;
    case 2:
        c=a-b;
        System.out.println("subtraction is = "+c);
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("press 1 & 2");
        ch=sc.nextInt();
        switch(ch)
        {

        case 1:
            if(a>b)
                d=b/a;
            System.out.println("divi is = "+d);
            //showing error = syntax error
            else
                System.out.println("");
            break;




        case 2:
                d=a/b;
            System.out.println("divistion is = "+d);
            break;

        }
        break;
    case 4:
        c=a*b;
        System.out.println("multiplication is = "+c);
        break;
        default :
            System.out.println("wrong input ");

    }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the syntax error? (Note that `if` is not a loop. It is more correct to say "if statement" instead.)

Comment: this is why it's good habit to use `{` `}` **all** the time.

Comment: What do you mean "if else looping"?

Comment: @EJoshuaS The OP means "if else statement"

Comment: I agree with @Aominè - please use `{` and `}` here.

Comment: "and one more doubt is how to prepare for the ocjp certification itself." Please ask one question at a time. But don't ask that as a separate question, it's too broad *and* off-topic. Given the very basic problems you're asking about here, my recommendation would be actually to learn the language before attempting to pass an exam.

Answer (score 4):

```
    if(a>b)
        d=b/a;
    System.out.println("divi is = "+d);
    //showing error = syntax error
    else
        System.out.println("");
```

The `else` isn't related to the `if`, because you've not got braces. What you've effectively written is:

```
    if(a>b) {
        d=b/a;
    }
    System.out.println("divi is = "+d);

    else
        System.out.println("");
```

Use braces:

```
    if(a>b) {
        d=b/a;
        System.out.println("divi is = "+d);
    } else {
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Note that some (e.g. [Google's style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1-braces)) would recommend always to use braces, even if there is just one statement between them.

Also note that this has nothing to do with being in a `switch` statement: you'd get exactly the same problem without the switch.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
case 1:
        if(a>b){
            d=b/a;
            System.out.println("divi is = "+d);
        }else
            System.out.println("");
        break;
```

In order to have more than one statement inside an `if` block, you need brackets to delimit it.

It's also good practice in Java to always use brackets to define blocks.

Comment: Indeed, that's a better definition.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have more than one statement for your if call before the else so you should enclose them in curly braces like this:

```
case 1:
        if(a>b)
        {
           d=b/a;
           System.out.println("divi is = "+d);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("");
        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
if(a>b)
        d=b/a;
    System.out.println("divi is = "+d);
    //showing error = syntax error
    else
        System.out.println("");
    break;
```

The

```
System.out.println("divi is = "+d);
```

is between the `if` and `else` statements.